# Why is my Hash Map insert function not working?

Tags: c, data-structures, hashmap

I am making a Hash Map with people's names as its key using C language. I am using separate chaining to resolve the collision.
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MinTableSize 1
#include <stdbool.h>
//Colission resolution Using linked list

struct ListNode;
typedef struct ListNode *Position;
struct HashTbl;
typedef struct HashTbl *HashTable;

typedef unsigned int Index;

Index Hash(const char *Key, int Tablesize)
{
    unsigned int HashVal = 0;
    while(*Key != '\0')
    {
        HashVal += *Key++;
    }
    return HashVal % Tablesize;
}

struct ListNode
{
    int Element;
    Position Next;
};

typedef Position List;
struct HashTbl
{
    int TableSize;
    List *TheLists;
};

//Function to find next prime number for the size
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(n <= 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 5; i*i <= n; i = i + 6)
    {
        if(n%i == 0 || n%(i + 2) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int NextPrime(int N)
{
    if(N <= 1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    int prime = N;
    bool found = false;

    while(!found)
    {
        prime++;
        if(isPrime(prime))
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}


HashTable InitializeTable(int TableSize)
{
    HashTable H;
    int i;
    if(TableSize < MinTableSize)
    {
        printf("Table size is too small\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    H = malloc(sizeof(struct HashTbl));
    if(H == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of space\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    H->TableSize = NextPrime(TableSize);
    H->TheLists = malloc(sizeof(List) * H->TableSize);
    if(H->TheLists == NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of space\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < H->TableSize; i++)
    {
        H->TheLists[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        if(H->TheLists[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Out of space\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            H->TheLists[i]->Next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return H;
}

//funtion to find the value
Position Find(const char *Key, HashTable H)
{
    Position P;
    List L;
    L = H->TheLists[Hash(Key, H->TableSize)];
    P = L->Next;
    while(P != NULL && P->Element != Key)
    {
        P = P->Next;
    }
    return P;
}

void Insert(const char *Key, HashTable H)
{
    Position Pos;
    Position NewCell;
    List L;
    Pos = Find(Key,  H);
    if(Pos == NULL)
    {
        NewCell = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        if(NewCell == NULL)
        {
            printf("Out of space\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            L = H->TheLists[Hash(Key, H->TableSize)];
            NewCell->Next;
            NewCell->Element = Key;
            L->Next = NewCell;
            printf("Key inserted\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Key already exist\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char Name[6][20] = {"Joshua", "Erica", "Elizabeth", "Monica", "Jefferson", "Andrian"};

    int Size = sizeof(Name[0])/sizeof(Name[0][0]);

    HashTable H = InitializeTable(Size);

    Insert(Name[0], H);
    Insert(Name[1], H);
    Insert(Name[2], H);
    Insert(Name[3], H);

}
```

The putout of this code is:

```
Key inserted
Key inserted
```

This means, it only successfully inserted two keys, while the other name has not been inserted. I think there's some error in my `Insert()` function, but I got no clue. I tried using an online compiler and it compile properly.

Comment: Please compile your code with compiler warnings enabled. Fix those first.

Comment: I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc and clang

Comment: Off-topic, but you shouldn't typedef pointers, that's just hiding information without any further value...

Comment: `.c:128:35: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  128 |     while(P != NULL && P->Element != Key)` is definitely an interesting one, did you mean to do a string comparison here?

Comment: `c:153:30: warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘const char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  153 |             NewCell->Element = Key;` and this one is rather fatal, you can't store strings in `int` elements.

Comment: Off-topic: Memory leak: `if(H->TheLists == NULL) { return NULL; }` – you already created the hash table object at this point so you need to free it again before returning.

Comment: [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) might be an interesting approach for you to avoid the memory leak, you only need one single allocation that way – though a bit of an advanced topic.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue. I am currently working on similar problem.